# Erro em query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Olá tenho uma tabela no banco de dados que nela estão armazenados vários horários.  E estou fazendo uma consulta só que esta dando erro.

Consulta:

```
select proximo from (select localizacao.horario as proximo from localizacao where localizacao.horario > CURRENT_TIME LIMIT 1) as tb_proximo, ultimo FROM (select localizacao.horario as ultimo from localizacao where localizacao.horario < CURRENT_TIME) as tb_ultimo;
```

Erro:

```
2 errors were found during analysis.

This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "FROM" at position 148)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "FROM" at position 148)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que tem aí alguma confusão na sua consulta. Esse `ultimo` está aí a mais, assim como o 2º `FROM`.

Experimente desta forma:

```
SELECT  (
            SELECT  localizacao.horario AS proximo 
            FROM    localizacao 
            WHERE   localizacao.horario > CURRENT_TIME LIMIT 1
        ) AS proximo
    ,   (
            SELECT  localizacao.horario AS ultimo 
            FROM    localizacao 
            WHERE   localizacao.horario < CURRENT_TIME
        ) AS ultimo
```

Comment: Sim a disposição é essa, deu certo, muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Dê a resposta como certa ;)